# Why does match-making in Game Center work for sandbox but not live?

Tags: ios, game-center, sandbox

I have a game that uses match-making in Game Center and everything worked great during testing in Sandbox. It went in the app store yesterday and now during match-making I get "Unable to create match. Please try again later.". I went back to my build in xcode and noticed that Game Center was turned OFF in the capabilities section. Is this the problem? If so why did it work in Sandbox?

I just want to make sure this is the problem before I resend since it is taking about a week per review and I want to get it right.

Comment: Also wanted to note that turning this on in capabilities was not mentioned in the tutorial I used

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have this turned on in your capabilities.